# How to make a list of columns

Tags: column

I have three functions: n, n^2, n^3. Range is 20 numbers. My task is to make a list of columns of **n, n^2, n^3** for numbers **n** upto 20. It supposed to look like this:
[image: expected output]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like searching for "column" in documentation?

Comment: Yes, there is literally no information in documentation.

Comment: First lookup 'literally' in google. Then 'column' in documentation, it already has some nice examples and in 'See also' section is a link to e.g. 'Tables and Matrices' tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for answer and sorry for my English, I came to the US 1.5 years ago, so I don't know English well enough.

Comment: It is not about english, sorry about that, I should not be ironic in comments. The main problem is lack of effort shown here. You simply can't say there is no info about 'column' in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
Column[#^{1, 2, 3}] & /@ Range[20]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly prettier than @Kuba's answer:

```
Grid[#^{1, 2, 3} & /@ Range[20], Frame -> All]
```

because the long list can extend down the page, though admittedly it doesn't match the poser's request perfectly.